# How to filter String which contain some combination of Charater and digits

Tags: regex, oracle

i would like to ask how can i filter column 'Product' which may contain 2 pattern:

1. it starts with 3 Character 'A-Z' or 'a-z' and followed by digits
   or

for example: ABC1258,acb548796

2. it start with Charater 'K' followed by digits, then '_', then other digits

for example: K123233_06565,K435_245
Thankyou

Comment: Have you have a look at `LIKE`, which supports pattern matching? What *have* you tried?

Comment: sorry, i am wrong, its oracle SQL not MSSQL. i have tried the first case: [A-ZA-z]{3}[0-9]+$

Comment: Well then, none of my comments stand (as SQL Server is not OPracle) apart from one: *"What have you tried?"*

Comment: @phalondon you are on the good way, but the second `A` should be lowercased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, which uses regular expressions.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'ABC1258'       from dual union all
  3     select 'K435_245'      from dual union all
  4     select 'AB_445'        from dual union all
  5     select 'KA234_23'      from dual union all
  6     select 'K12_BC'        from dual union all
  7     select 'XXX1243124YYY' from dual
  8    )
  9  select col
 10  from test
 11  where regexp_like(col, '^[[:alpha:]]{3}\d+$')
 12     or regexp_like(col, '^K\d+_\d+$');

COL
-------------
ABC1258
K435_245

SQL>
```

Comment: Thankyou alot Littefoot. i am beginner with REGEX. therefore can you please explain what is [:alpha:] and d+?

Comment: @phalondon - have a pipe at the Oracle documentation. As you might expect it covers Oracle's regex support. [Find it here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020).

Comment: You're welcome. `[[:alpha:]]` represents *letters* (such as `[A-Za-z]`), while `\d` represents *digits* (such as `[0-9]`). `+` means "give me one or more characters".

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a way to do that:

```
with tab as(
  select 'ABC1258' as str from dual union all
  select 'abc548796'as str from dual union all
  select 'K123233_06565'as str from dual union all
  select 'K435_245'as str from dual union all
  select 'X435_245'as str from dual union all
  select 'A435_245'as str from dual union all
  select 'KL435_245'as str from dual 
)

select *
from tab
where REGEXP_LIKE (str, '^([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]+)|(K[0-9]+_).*$');
```

**Result**:

```
ABC1258
abc548796
K123233_06565
K435_245
```